# "X will do for Y" vs. "X will do as Y"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consider the following sentences:

> - An empty box will do **for** a table.
> - The box will do fine **as** a table.

One uses *for*, the other *as*. Are the two interchangeable? Can the *for* be replaced with an *as* without affecting the meaning?

Comment: 'will do' just means 'serves the purpose' -- the preposition depends on the rest of the sentence. Note that 'for' here implies 'to function as'.

Answer (score 1):

Either one will do for/as a preposition in this context.